# GenServer implementation of an event handler not handling casts

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gen-server

I am trying to use [`GenServer`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html) as an event handler for [`EventBus`](https://github.com/otobus/event_bus) in my Phoenix application but for some reason I can't seem to figure out why the handle cast function isn't getting called. I checked that the process was alive with `:observer.start()`.

Is there something I'm missing for the `GenServer` to handle the cast call correctly?

Essentially the process function is supposed to handle an incoming event and cast it to the `GenServer` where the `GenServer` will handle the cast and perform domain logic on that event.

----Gen server module----

```
defmodule App.Notifications.EventHandler do
  use GenServer
  require Logger


  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], opts)
  end

  def init([]) do
    {:ok, []}
  end

  def process({topic_id, event_id}) do
    Logger.info("event notification process recieved!!") <---- THIS IS GETTING PRINTED!

    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {topic_id, event_id})
  end



def handle_cast({topic_id, event_id}, state) do
  Logger.info("event  notification data Recieved!!") <----- THIS IS NOT

  # do stuff

  {:noreply, state}
end


end
```

----App module-----

```
defmodule App.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application


  def start(_type, _args) do

    EventBus.subscribe({App.Notifications.EventHandler, ["^event_notification_created$"]})

    # List all child processes to be supervised
    children = [
      # Start the Ecto repository
      App.Repo,
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      AppWeb.Endpoint,
      # Starts a worker by calling: App.Worker.start_link(arg)
      # {App.Worker, arg},,
      App.Notifications.EventHandler <--- STARTING THE GEN SERVER HERE
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: App.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  # Tell Phoenix to update the endpoint configuration
  # whenever the application is updated.
  def config_change(changed, _new, removed) do
    App.Endpoint.config_change(changed, removed)
    :ok
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on [`GenServer.cast/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#cast/2) states, that the first parameter in call to `GenServer.cast/2` must be of a type [`server()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#t:server/0) which is:

> any of the values described in the “[Name registration](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration)” section of the documentation for this module.

In your code you start the link unnamed:

```rb
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], opts)
```

but then you cast to the named `GenServer`:

```rb
#              ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {topic_id, event_id})
```

The easiest way to fix it, start the server named:

```rb
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
```